# Segregate PRs from each other and unmerge branches from each other

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have a `dev` branch to merge my feature branches into. Practical situation.

Let's say I have 2 feature branches: `feaA` and `feaB`.
`feaA` is built on top of `dev`. `feaB` is built on top of `feaA`, so it has all the commits of `feaA`

(for files most likely irrelevant to `feaB`, `feaB` was built on top of `feaA` is for the reason, for example, when we want to perform some cleanup on `feaA`, and jump onto building `feaB` instead of `checkout dev` and create `feaB` branch off the `dev`).

1. How can I segregate `feaA` and `feaB` so the `feaB` doesn't have commits from `feaA`?
2. Assume, I already created 2 PRs, 1 from `feaA` to be merged into dev, and the other one from `feaB`. How can I segregate the 2 PRs, the goal is for code reviewer to have easier time reading the PR for `feaB` and not to be bothered by changes making to PR for `feaA`, while both PRs are still pending.

Command lines answers are warmly welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

rebase feaB discarding changes that belong to feaA:

```
git rebase --onto dev feaA feaB
```

Comment: can you explain your answer? If I understand you correctly, I should be doing `git checkout feaB` and write your cli, right? what branches get affected? does that affect `dev` branch? Your answer is for question 1 or 2? Thanks

Comment: Oh.... I didn't pay much attention to question 2.... and I don't have much experience working with PRs on github so won't risk providing an answer based on assumtions. My response is about question 1. No matter where you are, the command I provided will checkout dev branch (detached, branch won't move) and then it will apply (cherry-pick) all the revisions that belong to feaB that are **not** part of feaA. Then it will point feaB to the final revision of this process.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the two pull requests will be related and you just need to create **one pull request to merge `feaB` into `dev`**. That’s because `feaA` merge into `dev` or `feaB` merge into `dev` are both fast forward merge (as the graph below), so if `feaB` merged into `dev`, `feaA` will automatically merged into `dev` too.

```
A---B---C---D   dev
             \
              E---F---G     feaA
                       \
                         H---I---J   feaB
```

**Other branch structures suggestions.** You can refer below two structures based on your detail needs:

#### Option 1: create all feature branches from `dev`

If `dev` is your main branch, and all the features are different from others, you should create all feature branches from `dev`, and then create different PRs to merge them into `dev` separately.

```
              E---F---G   feaA
             /
A---B---C---D    dev
             \
              H---I---J   feaB
```

#### Option2: merge feature branches recursively

If your feature branches are related with each other (as `feaB` need some code/feature from `feaA` branch as the first graph shows), you can create a PR to merge `feaB` into `feaA` firstly. When the first PR is completed, then create a PR to merge `feaA` into `dev`.

Comment: Right with your saying of if feaB merged into dev, feaA will automatically merged into dev too. I appreciate your suggested options. Had Option 1 been strictly followed, things would be simple and easier for my reviewers. 


For feaB not to have feaA's commits, I thought of checking out `feaB` and doing `git rebase -i <commit_id for D>` (like in your example) and comment/delete the E,F,G commits from the rebase stack-trace. A drawback to this method is that If there are conflicts, I have to resolve conflicts per commit and do `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Yes, `git rebase -i` can rebase `feaB` to `dev`. And the conflicts is caused the versions between `D` and `H` (they have no directly relation before), so you just need to solve the conflicts for one time.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My reviewer had a way to unmerge the PRs effectively, showing on Bitbucket that the PR for feaB is unmerged from PR for feaA. I doubt that had been done within IntelliJ built-in VCS tool. Have you known the similar tricks?

Comment: It's mainly did by git commands directly. You can use the commands: `git checkout dev`, `git pull dev`, and `git reset --hard HEAD~` and `git push -f`. Then the new merged commit from `feaB` to `dev` will gone.